# Getting GPS location on Android Wear device

Tags: android, gps, location, wear-os, watch

I am trying to get GPS location on my Sony Smart Watch 3. The device has a built-in GPS, but I am not getting any location on it.

I am using the Android Location API to get location updates and have given the permission to the standalone app on the watch.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        mTextView.setText("" + location.getLatitude());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                    }
                });
```

Not sure if I am missing anything, but its pretty much what is needed to get location. In worst case Android Location API is not supported by Android Wear and only way to get location is using Google Fused Location API.

Comment: A quick check of the Sony site shows: "SmartWatch 3 SWR50 supports up to Android™ Wear 1.5. Android Wear 2.0 and onwards are not supported." So I believe the only way to get location is via the Google Fused Location API.

Answer (score 0):

You're either doing something wrong or not stood outside. I have the option in my app to use android location instead of the fuse to force watch GPS to turn on. Useful when going for a run to get GPS signal when still attached to phone and its working fine.